# Issues importing new FreePBX instance to GCP with TranslateFailed messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, freepbx

I configured a new install of FreePBX in VirtualBox and exported to an OVA file to be imported in GCP.  I can upload and kick off the import without issue however it fails each time with the following error:

[import-ovf]: 2020-01-14T15:47:09Z Error running workflow: step "translate" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-ovf-translate-translate-disk-98rv6": "TranslateFailed: error: command: No '/dev/log' or 'logger' included for syslog logging"

I am not quite sure how to get around it.  I've tried the Velostrata and Migrate RPM packages for CentOS (as that is what this distro is based on).  Has anyone else run into this issue and know how to get around it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Tried many recommendations to no success. (was following guide from [here](https://community.freepbx.org/t/how-to-install-freepbx-distro-with-commercial-modules-on-google-cloud-compute-engine-easier-and-secure/62065).)                                 
I opened a new [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/issues/1139) on github. Let's see if they post any solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue filed by *@Aron Einhorn* was solved at [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/issues/1139):

> The message No `/dev/log` or `logger` is a warning that occurs when a
> logging implementation is not found. So, a red herring in this case. I
> created [#1143](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/issues/1143) to fix that.
>
> Can you go back to your original centos7 machine, run depmod for each
> of the kernels, create another VHD, and import that? For depmod,
> something like this should work:
>
> `for i in /lib/modules/*; do depmod $(basename $i); done`